# Creating data for CSV file with multiple API Calls Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with an API and am able to make API calls to get my data back in JSON. It looks something like this

[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Fishing",
    "author": "Bob",
"publisher": {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "APublisher"
    }]

I then have another API call I am running using publisher ID to get more data about the publisher that comes back in JSON as well. How do I merge this data together? Its been a while since I have written anything this complicated in python and I can't remember if a dictionary is the best method and how to do it.

Note: my ultimate goal is to create a csv file with this data for an integration.

```
Code update:
#make call to get API data for books
books = json.loads(response1)
#make call to get API data for publisher
publisher = json.loads(response2)

books[0].publisher.update(json.loads(response2))
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably parse the JSON you received as a Python dict:

```
books = json.loads(response1)
```

Then if you get more data from the second API (still in JSON) you should also parse it as a Python dict, and you can update the values from the first one:

```
books[0]['publisher'].update(json.loads(response2))
```

Note that for your final goal (CSV), having nested dicts is not ideal as csv is a flat format. I would recommend to flatten it once you have the data:

```
def flatten_book(book):
    publisher = book.pop('publisher')
    for key, value in publisher.items():
         book['publisher_' + key] = value
    return book

for book in books:
    flatten_book(book)

# Now books would be something like:
# [ { "id": "1", "title": "Fishing", "author": "Bob", "publisher_id": "123", "publisher_name": "APublisher", "publisher_other_field": "value" }]
```

Comment: I am getting an error KeyError: 0 updating question with more details about my code.